# assembly 8086 array indexing in a loop

Tags: assembly, emu8086

im new to assembly and curently trying to create a program thet couculates the first 10 Fibonacci numbers.

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
fibo db 10 dup (0)
indx db 2
indxm db 1
CODESEG
start:
     mov ax, @data
     mov ds, ax
     mov [fibo+1], 1
     mov bx, 0
     mov cx, 8
next:
     mov ax, [fibo+indxm] ;here is the problem
     add [fibo+indx], ax ;also here
     inc indx
     inc indxm
     loop next 
exit:
     mov ax, 4c00h
     int 21h
END start
```

it doesnt work. how can i fix it???

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please be more specific — what is the question or issue exactly?

Comment: You can't add two memory addresses directly in x86 architecture, `add fibo[ind], fibo[indm]`

Comment: i fixed it but there is still the other problem. btw im using 8086

Comment: don't use memory as index, you cannot access [ <address1> + [ <address2 ] ] in a single instruction. take registers instead, preferable SI and DI to access the array, and increase these in the loop

Comment: it's pretty much unclear what you want to archive. a bit more info would be helpful

Comment: thank you very much Tommylee2k problem solved!